# Изменение имени страницы в WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress

В WP создаем страницу "Новости". Заходим на нее и по центру появляется название страницы (жирным шрифтом обычно). Как бы изменить именно это название на "Новости1" не изменяя при этом название (и ссылку) самой страницы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Название - есть название, если название страницы "Новости" то оно и будет "Новости", но вот ссылку вы можете изменить на любую, какую пожелаете. В редактировании страницы, под полем Название страницы есть ссылка и рядом кнопочка изменить.

Другой вариант, вы можете отключить плагином отображение названия "Новости" на этой странице, а в поле редактора уже написать "Новости1" и заключить в нужный тег или размер.

Comment: Да. Тоже догадался :) Именно так и сделал.